# Best practices for sending the same data to different databases?

Tags: php, mysql

There are multiple forms all leading to a CMS for our client and I want that data to also go through me to help us better target leads. Should I simply add in another prepared statement that sends the data to my server as well as the CMS or should I send the data to my server and the re-route to the CMS?

Comment: You want to do _what_? Use your clients data for your own purpose? I hope very well that you have your clients consense here?

Comment: In general it is an uncommon approach to use an additional explicit database for such thing. Usually such information is either taken from the CMS logs which are sent into some elastic search setup like graylogging or an ELK. Also some processing queue is often used, something like RabbitMQ or similar from where some analysing tool polls the data.

Comment: @arkascha This is all done with consent. Before when we built their site we had forms people would fill out and the leads would go directly to our client because we didn't have any use for the data only the number of leads coming in. We want to better target demographics with PPC and SEO so now we are looking to gather and store the information to help that effort.

Comment: I think I answered to that in my second comment. It still sounds strange to me. Make sure, really really sure, that you are on a safe side from a legal point of view. That is sensitive data you are talking about, it is protected by privacy rules nearly everywhere on the world for very good reasons.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need to store the same data, you're looking to store the *metadata* which can be generated at the same time and simply sent to a different DB. I hope for your sake all the DBs are on the same server?

Comment: If your company is EU based this can directly contravene the GDPR and will be a massive hassle to work with (maintaining two database record sets in tandem)

Comment: @Martin To me "leads" and "targets" does not sound like meta data but specific, customer centric data points.

Comment: @arkascha OP doesn't seem to need the leads, simply the *quantity* of leads generated. I may be wrong, it could be ambiguous

Comment: @Martin No, in contrary. The numbers are what they already have. Now the goal is to collect more detailed data. (as I read this)

Comment: Why can't you just use Google Analytics on the site?

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found for duplicating databases is through replication. Take a look at MySQL's chapter on replication here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html